# Gradient of a function with base vectors

Tags: tensors, vector-fields, derivatives

\begin{align}
\nabla\left(x_1x_3\hat{e}_1+x_2x_3\hat{e}_2\right)&=x_3\left(\hat{e}_1\otimes\hat{e}_1\right)+x_3\left(\hat{e}_2\otimes\hat{e}_2\right)\\&+\mathbf{x_1\left(\hat e_1\otimes\hat{e}_3\right)+x_2\left(\hat e_2\otimes\hat e_3\right)}
\end{align}

Where did the terms in bold come from?

Comment: I believe I copied your text correctly into LaTeX. Could you verify that this is correct?

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for math.SE?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use that
$$
\nabla f = \frac{\partial{f}}{x_1}\hat{e}_1+\frac{\partial{f}}{x_2}\hat{e}_2+\frac{\partial{f}}{x_1}\hat{e}_3
$$
Then you get
$$
\nabla(x_1 x_3)= x_3\hat{e}_1+x_1\hat{e}_3
$$
and
$$
\nabla(x_2 x_3)= x_3\hat{e}_2+x_2\hat{e}_3.
$$
The second summands in the last two equations then give you the cross terms
$$
\nabla(x_1 x_3 \hat{e}_1+x_2 x_3 \hat{e}_2)= (x_3\hat{e}_1+x_1\hat{e}_3)\otimes\hat{e}_1+(x_3\hat{e}_2+x_2\hat{e}_3)\otimes\hat{e}_2.
$$